# I want to download Directory and all contents of this with Wget

Tags: svn, wget

I am trying to download all the contents of agi folder and the folder inside it 
using commands. It is just downloading index.html instead of all folders and files inside it

```
wget -r   -l2 --user Shailesh.k --password password  https://x.x.x/svn/Switch/branches/1.0.0/agi/ --no-check-certificate
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `wget` for this. You should use Subversion client for this task. Run [`svn export`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) command.